# Maximum value for IIS .NET Compilation Batch Time-out

Tags: iis, pre-compilation

What is the maximum value for the IIS -> .NET Compilation -> Batch -> time-out ?

i need to set it to maximum in order to avoid compilation cannot be completed within the time-out period, the compiler reverts to single-compilation mode for the current page.

Comment: @Will: what i meant is Max value for time-out by set it using IIS Manager.

Comment: `int.MaxValue`?  Try it and see.  It's going to be a short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, etc.  That's a small number of candidates.  Take each value in turn and try it.  Tada!  Answer at hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value internally is 2147483647 (32-bit signed integer). In the UI of IIS you have to specify the value as hh:mm:ss, so that would be something like:
596523 hours or 68 years.

I think even if your site exceeds the default value of 15 minutes you have a problem with your application.

By the way, to find this value, open:

```
%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\ASPNET_schema.xml
```

and search for `batchTimeout`

Comment: i think it is normal for a commercial web site with 2000 ++ (.aspx and ascx) pages to exceeds the default time-out.